# Live in same space of memory

Tags: java

I have a question.

Example:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String a = "hello";

        String b = a;

        a = "bye";


        System.out.println(b);

        //Output: "hello"

    }

}
```

Why? 
"a" does not live the same space in memory as "b"?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You assign `b = a` so they refer to the same object. Then you assign `a =` something else, so they are now different objects.

Comment: what's the status of this question? You've been given answers; it should be marked as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String a = "hello"; // a is a reference to the "hello" string object

String b = a; // b is a reference to the same "hello" string object

a = "bye"; // a is updated to reference the "bye" string object
           // b is still referencing the "hello" string object

System.out.println(b); // "hello" is printed
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write

> ```
> String b = a;
> ```

You *are not* saying "`b` will now and forever more point to the same thing as `a`".

Instead, you are saying "assign `a`'s value to `b`". *Until a new assignment is made*, both `a` and `b` will point to the same object, but as soon as you assign either `a` or `b` a new value, this will stop being true.